# NUI + Custom font. Text are cut by half

Tags: ios, custom-font, nui

I use `NUI` ( https://github.com/tombenner/nui ) and I want to display text in button with certain font and size. Here is my 'css' file:

```
accessoryButton {
    font-name: GothamSSm-Light;
    font-size: 20;
    font-color: white;
}
```

And what I get from it (screenshot with blended layers):

[image: damaged text].

And it happens not only with button, I tried the same on `UITextField` - same result. If I change font-name on `Arial`, for example, text appears correctly. 
I've checked that font on test project without `NUI`, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with improperly formatted `ttf` files. the trick is to manually edit the `hhea` table. [Check out this awesome article](http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/) which explains exactly how to do it:

Comment: Good article. Mb this is it, but I cannot reconstruct my font using specified tools. Anyway thank you, you give me a clue, I will investigate it tomorrow and if you really guess right I mark this answer as correct.
Oh, and I'm using .otf font

Comment: IOS uses ttf's though, so I am not sure how that is working for you at all. What is preventing you from using the tool?

Comment: It was a late night and I specified a xml file instead of font in second command - for reconstructing=)

Thank you, man, you made my day!

Comment: As a tip, if you use git, using SourceTree you can see the visual difference from old version to new one :)